# What did Amy drink out of the red plastic cup in the bathroom?

Tags: plot-explanation, booksmart

In *Booksmart*, Amy is in the bathroom with another girl. Amy becomes embarrassed, grabs a random red plastic cup, and drinks what's in it. She immediately regrets it. She also spits something solid out of her mouth.

What did she spit out of her mouth? Was it a cigarette butt? What was in the cup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having watch it again it looks like a cigarette butt, if you remember when she walks into the bathroom Hope is smoking something, so she was probably putting them out in the cups there. So assuming it contained some form of alcohol, mixed with a cigarette butt (or multiple). Not nice.

Comment: I forgot she was smoking in the bathroom! That makes sense.

Comment: I watched the movie twice, and the second time I paid close attention because at first I thought it had to do with her story about throwing up on her mom.  Then I realized the cup was full of cigarette butts.  The scene was more or less stolen from a similar scene from Caddyshack, sans the lesbian tryst.